# Sort a list of 20 variables, and pick the top five

Tags: javascript, arrays

So here is my dilemma, and I've done a few days worth of research to try to find out how to solve it.

Problem: I have function that reads rows of an xml file with js that then stores certain rows (a1, a2, a3, etc.) to variable/array. I then need to sort them by value, and choose the top five biggest numbers and use their ids to choose other information from the xml files.

For example I have a1, a4, a5, a6, and a2 are my biggest rows for this file (the values change from file to file). I then need to, with those variables picked, grab data from 10 rows with similar names and perform a math equation on them (the new rows are the same as the first except with a "a" or a "b" on the end).

My theoretical solution: Read the rows from the xml into an array, and read the corresponding rows into two more arrays. Then when I sort the first array, i can take the cell names of the top five arrays and use that to define which array cells i use from the other two arrays to complete my equation.

Here are my three arrays.

```
indSort[0] = Number($(this).find("n0").text());
indSort[1] = Number($(this).find("n1").text());
indSort[2] = Number($(this).find("n2").text());
indSort[3] = Number($(this).find("n3").text());
indSort[4] = Number($(this).find("n4").text());
indSort[5] = Number($(this).find("n5").text());
indSort[6] = Number($(this).find("n6").text());
indSort[7] = Number($(this).find("n7").text());
indSort[8] = Number($(this).find("n8").text());
indSort[9] = Number($(this).find("n9").text());
indSort[10] = Number($(this).find("n10").text());
indSort[11] = Number($(this).find("n11").text());
indSort[12] = Number($(this).find("n12").text());
indSort[13] = Number($(this).find("n13").text());
indSort[14] = Number($(this).find("n14").text());
indSort[15] = Number($(this).find("n15").text());
indSort[16] = Number($(this).find("n16").text());
indSort[17] = Number($(this).find("n17").text());
indSort[18] = Number($(this).find("n18").text());
indSort[19] = Number($(this).find("n19").text());
indSort[20] = Number($(this).find("n20").text());

indSorta[0] = Number($(this).find("n0a").text());
indSorta[1] = Number($(this).find("n1a").text());
indSorta[2] = Number($(this).find("n2a").text());
indSorta[3] = Number($(this).find("n3a").text());
indSorta[4] = Number($(this).find("n4a").text());
indSorta[5] = Number($(this).find("n5a").text());
indSorta[6] = Number($(this).find("n6a").text());
indSorta[7] = Number($(this).find("n7a").text());
indSorta[8] = Number($(this).find("n8a").text());
indSorta[9] = Number($(this).find("n9a").text());
indSorta[10] = Number($(this).find("n10a").text());
indSorta[11] = Number($(this).find("n11a").text());
indSorta[12] = Number($(this).find("n12a").text());
indSorta[13] = Number($(this).find("n13a").text());
indSorta[14] = Number($(this).find("n14a").text());
indSorta[15] = Number($(this).find("n15a").text());
indSorta[16] = Number($(this).find("n16a").text());
indSorta[17] = Number($(this).find("n17a").text());
indSorta[18] = Number($(this).find("n18a").text());
indSorta[19] = Number($(this).find("n19a").text());
indSorta[20] = Number($(this).find("n20a").text());

indSortb[0] = Number($(this).find("n0b").text());
indSortb[1] = Number($(this).find("n1b").text());
indSortb[2] = Number($(this).find("n2b").text());
indSortb[3] = Number($(this).find("n3b").text());
indSortb[4] = Number($(this).find("n4b").text());
indSortb[5] = Number($(this).find("n5b").text());
indSortb[6] = Number($(this).find("n6b").text());
indSortb[7] = Number($(this).find("n7b").text());
indSortb[8] = Number($(this).find("n8b").text());
indSortb[9] = Number($(this).find("n9b").text());
indSortb[10] = Number($(this).find("n10b").text());
indSortb[11] = Number($(this).find("n11b").text());
indSortb[12] = Number($(this).find("n12b").text());
indSortb[13] = Number($(this).find("n13b").text());
indSortb[14] = Number($(this).find("n14b").text());
indSortb[15] = Number($(this).find("n15b").text());
indSortb[16] = Number($(this).find("n16b").text());
indSortb[17] = Number($(this).find("n17b").text());
indSortb[18] = Number($(this).find("n18b").text());
indSortb[19] = Number($(this).find("n19b").text());
indSortb[20] = Number($(this).find("n20b").text());
```

Any help would be super great!!!!

EDIT: I'm also open to doing things differently. Examples would really help.

Comment: Are you seriously using that code?

Comment: Let me introduce you to your new best friend... the `for` loop.

Comment: Your code so far is the same (except much slower because of all the jQuery objects you create) than `var $this = $(this); for(var i = 0; i <= 20; i++){ indSort.push(+$this.find('n' + i)); indSorta.push(+$this.find('n' + i + 'a')); indSortb.push(+$this.find('n' + i + 'b')); }` Which with proper formatting would also be a lot more readable.

Comment: Behold - the mighty and mysterious [`for statement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for), it will amplify your powers and curses your enemies with fear. Handle with care, as its fragile nature could even destroy the universe itself! (Nah, it won't, but seriously, [don't repeat yourself!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_Repeat_Yourself))

Comment: The for statement would work, except in the actual xml file i have (supplied by client) is like n11, n32, n57, and in a weird order like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [custom compare function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) for `.sort()`, where you may compare some values of the rows against each other. Then use just:

```
array.sort(customCompare).slice(0, 5);
```

Comment: I'll play around with this and get back to you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An elegant way to sort your elements:

```
$(this).find("*").sort(function(a, b){
  return +b.innerHTML-a.innerHTML;
})
```

After you can use slice() to get the first 5 elements